# Javascript to change image depending on time

Tags: javascript, date, time, background

Basically, I've got a script which changes the page background depending on the time.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
day=new Date()     //..get the date
x=day.getHours()    //..get the hour

if(x>=0 && x<4) {

   document.write('<style type="text/css">#header{background: white url(images/assets/1st.jpg); color: black}"></style>')

} else

if(x>=4 && x<12) {

   document.write('<style type="text/css">#header{background: white url(images/assets/2nd.jpg); color: black}"></style>')

} else

if(x>=12 && x<18) {

   document.write('<style type="text/css">#header{background: white url(images/assets/3rd.jpg); color: black}"></style>')

} else

if (x>=18 && x<24) {

   document.write('<style type="text/css">#header{background: white url(images/assets/4th.jpg); color: black}"></style>')

}
```

So as you can see, the first background changes between at 4am and so on.

What I would look to do is to change the background at different times every day, reading from some sort of text file or something. For example, on the 10th June the first background changes at 4:15am and the others with different times, on the 11th June the first background changes at 4:22am or something and so on.

Could someone possibly find me or write me something to do this? I can't find anything anywhere!

Thanks ever so much

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by rewriting the script in a more modern form (i.e. using a script tag that is not deprecated, declaring variables...), and putting the settings in an array to make it more configurable:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var now = new Date();
var date = (now.getMonth() + 1) * 100 + now.getDate();
var time = now.getHours() * 100 + now.getMinutes();

var settings = [
  { date: 1224, time: 2400, image: 'xmas.jpg'}, // all christmas eve
  { date: 704, time: 2400, image: 'bang.jpg'}, // all fourth of july
  // any other day:
  { date: -1, time: 400, image: '1st.jpg'},
  { date: -1, time: 1200, image: '2nd.jpg'},
  { date: -1, time: 1800, image: '3rd.jpg'},
  { date: -1, time: 2400, image: '4th.jpg'}
];

var setting;
for (var i = 0; i < settings.length; i++) {
  var s = settings[i];
  if ((s.date == -1 || s.date == date) && time < s.time) {
    setting = settings[i];
    break;
  }
}

document.write('<style type="text/css">#header{background: white url(images/assets/'+setting.image+'); color: black}</style>');

</script>
```

Note: I removed a spurios `">` in the style sheet code.

#### Edit:

I added code for handling dates, and simplified the time format. At the end of the settings you have items with `date: -1` which apply to any date that is not earlier in the settings.

Comment: what is the +0 for in 4*60+0 ?

Comment: @mplungjan: It's for minutes, so 4*60+15 is 4:15.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for clearing it up! :D
I do have a question, What would I add in settings to specify a different day and time?

Comment: Thanks for that but unfortunately it doesn't seem to be working :/
I've copied and pasted what you've put up there, saved it but the background doesn't change at all. However, I am getting a syntax error on this line `for (var i = 0; i < settings.length) {
` if that might be related?

Comment: @Mohsin: I forgot an `i++` in there: `for (var i = 0; i < settings.length; i++) {`.

Comment: Wow!!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH! :D
It works as intended and its perfect! Kudos to you!

Now I have to add 30 days with timings, oh the joys of being a web developer.

Comment: Oh dear, something's not right it seems. If I set the time to 2359 or below, the images won't change. I don't know if it's a problem with something I've changed by accident or something, but I've tried replacing it from the above and it still doesn't work.

Another problem I am having is the script won't follow my CSS styles as intended. I haven't changed any of my CSS properties either. Here's a screenshot of before and after: http://d.pr/FtFn

Comment: This is what I have in my script:

`var settings = [
  // any other day:
  { date: -1, time: 700, image: 'fajr.png', moon: 'moon-AM.png'},
  { date: -1, time: 2400, image: 'fajr.png', moon: 'moon-PM.png'},
];

var setting;
for (var i = 0; i < settings.length; i++) {
  var s = settings[i];
  if ((s.date == -1 || s.date == date) && time < s.time) {
    setting = settings[i];
    break;
  }
}

document.write('<style type="text/css">#header{background: white url(images/assets/'+setting.image+'); color: black} #moon{background: white url(images/assets/'+setting.moon+'); color: black}</style>');
`

Comment: @Mohsin: I tried the code, and it does select different settings depending on the time. You are using the same value for the `image` property in both settings, can that be the reason why the image won't change?

Comment: `// any other day:
  { date: -1, time: 700, image: 'fajr.png', moon: 'moon-AM.png'},
  { date: -1, time: 1900, image: 'maghrib.png', moon: 'moon-PM.png'},`

Tried that and the background doesn't even show at all

Comment: The last setting has to have `date: -1, time: 2400` so that there is always a setting that matches. With your settings the last image will stop being displayed at 19:00.

Comment: Ah, that explains that then. What about the CSS not behaving properly? :(

Comment: @Mohsin: As far as I can see, you are using a background color along with the image, which will acount for the white square around the image. You should add `no-repeat` for the background setting also, so that the images are not repeated.

Comment: Hmm that has helped to a certain extent, except it won't follow the width: 100% property for the background I've set. When I do set it it in the scripts stylesheet, it just leaves a blank space

Comment: @Mohsin: I'm not sure what you are trying to do. You can't set width on a background image.

Answer (score 0):

On the server, place the file in a format such as JSON or XML with information about changes in the background.

For example something like this: (file: http://example.com/bg.json)

```
{
    "default": {
        "00:00": "http://example.com/image1.png",
        "04:00": "http://example.com/image2.png",
        "10:00": "http://example.com/image3.png",
        "18:00": "http://example.com/image4.png",
    },
    // In format DD/MM/YYYY
    // This means that every Christmast (every year)
    "24/12" : {
        "00:00": "http://example.com/mary-xmas.png"
    },
    // and so on ...
}
```

Next you wil load this file by jQuery json (ajax) page's url is for example http://example.com/index.html:

```
$(function() {
      $.ajax({
          url: 'bg.json',
          type: 'json',
          success: function(data) {
              // In data you have complete object, you can easily parse it
              // and create timer to change the background 
          }
      });
  });
```

And for changing background rather use this:

```
$('#header').css('background', 'white url(...) scroll no-repeat 0 0');
```

Thi exaple needs jQuery, but it is not too hard to rewrite it to pure JavaScript or to another framework like Prototype or Mootools.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This implementation definitely looks a lot easier than the JS one but I guess it still needs the original JS?
If it does then I'll see about merging the two together or using from each other etc, I really like this idea though!

Definitely saving this, thanks for your help :)

Comment: This code expects using javascript framework called jQuery. But this is just demonstration. You can use pure javascript but I recomend you to use some framework, which will save you a lot of time. Take a look to some of them: jQuery, Prototype, Mootools